# jQuery Check user's input before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to validate user's input before they submit the form. Although I'm successful doing so when they hit the button, somehow I couldn't make it also stop when they press the enter key:

HTML:

```
   <form method='post' class='submit_form' action="<?php echo base_url();?>interview/reserve_temporary">
        <input type="text" class="form-control email_input" id="reserve_email_2" placeholder="Email">
        <button type="button" id="subscribe_2" class="btn btn-default text-center foot-submit-btn subscribe_button">Let me try</button>
   </form>
```

JS:

```
  $('.submit_form').submit(function(e) { 

      var email = $(this).find('.email_input').val();
      var id=$(this).find('.subscribe_button').attr('id').split("_").pop(); 

      var regex_email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

      if (regex_email.test(email)||email.match(/^\d+$/)) {
          $(this).text('Sending……');
      }
      else {
          return false;
      }
 }
```

Comment: What you want to validate? Check if user press the submit button with empty string?

Comment: Check if the string they put in meet the regex requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$('.submit_form').submit(function(e) { 

    var email = $(this).find('.email_input').val();
    var id=$(this).find('.subscribe_button').attr('id').split("_").pop(); 

    var regex_email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (regex_email.test(email)||email.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        $(this).text('Sending……');
        return true
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I updated the question by deleting the unnecessary messy parts which somehow escaped my previous inspection. I also tried your code, but it just submits straight away without validating anything.

Comment: Well, that's not too surprising. I find this approach to be pretty inconsistent, but I've posted an alternative approach that is based upon preventing the default event if your validation fails. Give it another go.

Comment: Well, can I ask what expression you are using to test? There is another approach that is not fun, but have you at least checked to see that the function is being called? It might be helpful at this point to set up a jsfiddle

Comment: I got it worked eventually. The if conditions are not being met which caused the avalanche of troubles. I changed the condition to if (0<1) and the function is running. I will need to work on that part later. But thanks again for the help! Super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a more easy option to validate your inputs
check jquery validation engine ,an easy&powerful validation tool
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer stay on JS and JQuery though.